# How can I determine the sequence of events when timestamp cannot be trusted?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Our order processing software keeps the most recent values of things like sales value in the transactional table, and creates a row in an audit table whenever there is a change (including timestamp, before value, after value). For reporting purposes I want to be able to find the initial value, then step through each change to end up at the current value.

However, the system only saves changes periodically, and I'm not sure how but it will occasionally save them to the database (and so timestamp them) out of order.

I would like to iterate over these rows and determine the true order of updates based on both timestamp proximity and before/after values.

This is an example of the changes to the gross sales value of an order over time:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
|    date_created     | before_value_string | after_value_string |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| 2019-09-04 12:48:36 |                 438 |                876 |
| 2019-09-04 12:48:43 |                 876 |               1314 |
| 2019-09-04 12:48:43 |                   0 |                438 |
| 2019-09-04 12:49:48 |                1314 |               1752 |
| 2019-09-04 14:00:35 |                1752 |               1314 |
| 2019-09-04 14:00:49 |                1314 |                876 |
| 2019-09-04 14:00:55 |                 876 |                438 |
| 2019-09-05 09:03:50 |                 438 |                538 |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
```

Looking at the before_value_string field, it is clear that row 3 should in fact be first. In addition, rows 2 and 3 have the same timestamp so there is no reliable way to order them (this happens a lot).

There are two instances where before_value_string is 876 but after_value_string is different - the solution will have to be careful to order these correctly.

I have tried using date_trunc() to group transactions by minute which has helped, but as I cannot guarantee that out-of-order transactions all occurred in the same minute period this is not a reliable solution:

```
SELECT
  parent_id,
  date_created,
  CASE
    WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 0
    ELSE COALESCE(MAX(before_value_string::decimal(38, 2)), 0)
  END AS init_amount,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parent_id
    ORDER BY
    CASE
      WHEN COUNT(date_trunc('minute', date_created)) > 1
      AND before_value_string::DECIMAL(38, 2) = 0 THEN 1
      ELSE 2
    END,
    DATE_TRUNC('minute', date_created)) AS ranked
FROM
  src.orders_audit
WHERE
  field_name = 'amount'
AND
  date_created > date_entered
GROUP BY
 1, 2, before_value_string
```

This is the desired output:

```
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------+--------+
|              parent_id               |    date_created     | init_amount | ranked |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------+--------+
| 256493a0-cf0f-11e9-9bcc-42010a9a0005 | 2019-09-04 12:48:43 |        0.00 |      1 |
| 256493a0-cf0f-11e9-9bcc-42010a9a0005 | 2019-09-04 12:48:36 |      438.00 |      2 |
| 256493a0-cf0f-11e9-9bcc-42010a9a0005 | 2019-09-04 12:48:43 |      876.00 |      3 |
| 256493a0-cf0f-11e9-9bcc-42010a9a0005 | 2019-09-04 12:49:48 |    1,314.00 |      4 |
| 256493a0-cf0f-11e9-9bcc-42010a9a0005 | 2019-09-04 14:00:55 |      876.00 |      5 |
| 256493a0-cf0f-11e9-9bcc-42010a9a0005 | 2019-09-04 14:00:35 |    1,752.00 |      6 |
| 256493a0-cf0f-11e9-9bcc-42010a9a0005 | 2019-09-04 14:00:49 |    1,314.00 |      7 |
| 256493a0-cf0f-11e9-9bcc-42010a9a0005 | 2019-09-05 09:03:50 |      438.00 |      8 |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------+--------+
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS src.orders_audit ( 
    id CHAR(36) NOT NULL ENCODE RAW 
   ,parent_id CHAR(36) ENCODE lzo 
   ,date_created TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE ENCODE lzo 
   ,created_by VARCHAR(36) ENCODE lzo 
   ,field_name VARCHAR(100) ENCODE lzo 
   ,data_type VARCHAR(100) ENCODE lzo 
   ,before_value_string VARCHAR(255) ENCODE lzo 
   ,after_value_string VARCHAR(255) ENCODE lzo 
   ,before_value_text VARCHAR(256) ENCODE lzo 
   ,after_value_text VARCHAR(256) ENCODE lzo 
   ,PRIMARY KEY (id) ) DISTSTYLE ALL SORTKEY ( id );
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. If there is no way to do this in Redshift that would also be an acceptable answer.

Comment: I don't think there is a deterministic solution (for instance, you have repeat values over time).  Even if there were, I think it would require recursive CTEs, which Redshift does not support.

Comment: I think you could probably self join the table a bunch of times to approximate a recursive CTE.  If you were to self join 9 times you would get up to the first 9 changes.  Might have to unpivot the results.

Comment: I don't know much about Redshift. But I can't think of any dbms I've used in the past 30 years whose timestamp data type offered only one-second precision. Is this a Redshift limitation, a user interface default, a configuration option, or something like that? That is, can we get more precision out of Redshift's timestamps?

Comment: The timestamp data comes from a datetime field in  a MySQL database. I do not believe it is stored with sub-second precision in there. Regardless, we still have rows being inserted seconds out, so increased precision unfortunately wouldn't solve that issue.

Comment: [MySQL supports fractional seconds in datetime data types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html), but it doesn't conform to SQL standards. *"We still have rows being inserted seconds out"* Sorry, but I don't get it. What does *being inserted seconds out* mean?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that the order that rows are inserted is incorrect, with the timestamps differing by multiple seconds rather than just milliseconds. In the example provided, row 3 was inserted at 12:48:43 but occurred client-side before row 1 (inserted at 12:48:36).

Comment: @DavidB: Paste the `create table ...` statement.

Comment: For which table? I'm not sure how that will help?

Comment: @DavidB: There's only one table in your query.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS src.orders_audit
(
 id CHAR(36) NOT NULL  ENCODE RAW
 ,parent_id CHAR(36)   ENCODE lzo
 ,date_created TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE   ENCODE lzo
 ,created_by VARCHAR(36)   ENCODE lzo
 ,field_name VARCHAR(100)   ENCODE lzo
 ,data_type VARCHAR(100)   ENCODE lzo
 ,before_value_string VARCHAR(255)   ENCODE lzo
 ,after_value_string VARCHAR(255)   ENCODE lzo
 ,before_value_text VARCHAR(256)   ENCODE lzo
 ,after_value_text VARCHAR(256)   ENCODE lzo
 ,PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
DISTSTYLE ALL
 SORTKEY (
 id
 );`

Comment: @DavidB: Where does the value for 'date_created' come from?

Comment: This table is copied from a Postgres table which is copied from MySQL table which is populated through various PHP scripts. I do not have the ability to change any of those scripts but have already escalated to the dev team that this is an issue.